Create Custom microROS Messages in PlatformIO
I am trying to create a ROS service on my NodeMCU Esp32S. Therefore I am using the micro_ros_platformio library.
After including everything into PlatformIO (as shown in the libraries readme), I was able to successfully run my first programs.
Because the message for the service I want to offer does not exist in the standard messages in the way I need it, I had to create a custom service message.

Since I then had to create a custom service message for my application, I created a new workspace custom_interfaces_ws with a new ROS2 package custom_message, containing both a msgand a srv folder and build them like you usually would build ROS2 messages.
After creating the messages, I referenced them in my platformio.ini:
[env:nodemcu-32s]
platform = espressif32
board = nodemcu-32s
framework = arduino
board_microros_distro = humble
board_microros_transport = wifi
lib_deps = 
    https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_platformio

extra_scripts = 
    pre:read_config.py

monitor_speed = 115200

build_flags = 
    -I/home/nash/dev/ros_custom_interfaces_ws/install/custom_messages/include
    -I/home/nash/dev/ros_custom_interfaces_ws/install/custom_messages/include/custom_messages
    -L/home/nash/dev/ros_custom_interfaces_ws/install/custom_messages/lib
    -lcustom_messages__rosidl_typesupport_c
    -lcustom_messages__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c

Running this led me to the problem, that the file format of my .so files was not recognized
and returned the following error:

/home/nash/dev/ros_custom_interfaces_ws/install/custom_messages/lib/libcustom_messages__rosidl_typesupport_c.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/nodemcu-32s/firmware.elf] Error 1

(which was somehow expectable, since I was just building the messages on my machine)

Since my first approach failed, I tried to stick to the micro ros tutorial on how to include custom messages.
I created a new firmware with the ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_firmware_ws.sh freertos esp32 command, created a new package with my custom messages in the firmware/mcu_ws folder and configured the firmware by running ros2 run micro_ros_setup configure_firmware.sh ping_pong --transport serial.
The reason why I ran the configuration step with the ping pong app is, because you can't build the firmware in the next step, without running the configuration step before. But because I didn't create a custom application (since I am running everything over PlatformIO, but need the libraries to be build for the esp32 platform), I was hoping to build the firmware with my custom messages in it and afterwards reference the built messages PlatformIO, like I did in my first approach. This also didn't work out.

Is it even possible to create custom messages solely with the PlatformIO build tools or to create custom messages for microROS, using the micro_ros_platformio library?

You can create a directory named extra_packages on the main tree of your platformio code. Then on that directory, add the 'custom_message' folder that also resides on the custom_interfaces_ws directory. Delete the .pio directory and then build your project. Then you should be able to use your custom msg and srv files from your code. https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/blob/jazzy/examples/micro-ros_addtwoints_service/micro-ros_addtwoints_service.ino shows how to run a custom service from microROS using Arduino framework
